# Is Hybris tenant like a process?

Tags: java, junit, multi-tenant, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using the core and junit tenant on Hybris for tests, and i'm new with this platform.

Are Hybris tenants like process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compare it with Spring profiles: when you have different configuration for application on production(development) and testing environment.
You can have different DB tables in use (like with junit_ prefix as example).
In scope of one started application with active master tenant for current moment it is possible to have threads which know nothing about current tenant (like Hybris hotfolder engine).